# Delete all windows files in a particular folder which is before current month

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file

Can I have your help & expertise in creating a batch file for the below please

I have below files in a folder `\\abcdef123\test\root\child\source`

```
AC_FDM_TREE_EXTRACT_20161216203034.touch
AC_FDM_TREE_EXTRACT_20170118204420.touch
AC_FDM_TREE_EXTRACT_20170214204730.touch
PS_Z_VT_SUPER_TREE_20161216203034.txt
PS_Z_VT_SUPER_TREE_20170118204420.txt
PS_Z_VT_SUPER_TREE_20170214204730.txt
```

I would like to dynamically delete all files except for the current month.
ie., If YYYYMM is the current month, delete all files(do not include sub folders) not equal to *YYYYMM*.*

It is unlikely that files will be generated with future dates. But, if it is a quick win, may be say delete all files before current month is even better.

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: [using FORFILES in batch to delete tmp and bak files older than a week](//superuser.com/q/650800)

Comment: This one is as easy as pie yet you've not even taken a stab at something to show what work you've put into your task. There are many ways to complete this but there's a simple and easy solution with pure batch but you've not shown what you've tried that you're having trouble with... Too bad, so sad!!

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to dynamically delete all files except for the current month. ie., If YYYYMM is the current month, delete all files(do not include sub folders) not equal to YYYYMM.*

Here is a PowerShell script that does it:

```
Push-Location "\\abcdef123\test\root\child\source"

$USculture=New-Object -TypeName CultureInfo -ArgumentList "en-US"
$targetDateString=(Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMM", $USculture)

Remove-Item * -Exclude ("*"+$targetDateString+"*")
Pop-Location
```

The first line changes the folder to "\abcdef123\test\root\child\source"

The second and third line (second paragraph) gets the current year and month of the Gregorian calendar in the "yyyyMM" format, where "yyyy" is a four-digits year and "MM" is a two-digits month.

The fourth line (last paragraph) deletes all files in the current folder except those that match the "*yyyyMM*" pattern.

The last line returns you to the folder where you started.

Comment: Thanks Fleet Command. Can you suggest a beginnners link to PowerShell?

Comment: @Learner16, I'll go over my bookmarks to see which one is suitable for what you want. In the mean time, if you find the answer what you wanted, please don't forget to click on the large checkmark near the answer.